# Mailer doesn't send emails. Rails 5. Hostgator mail server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, mailer

There was gmail smtp settings before and emails were sent, but I change smtp settings on hostgator settings -

```
> smtp_settings:
>     :address: gator3287.hostgator.com
>     :port: 465
>     :domain: my_site.com
>     :user_name: noreply@my_site.com
>     :password: password
>     :authentication: plain
>     :enable_starttls_auto: true   
> default:
>     :from: noreply@floorwatch.com
>     :to: noreply@floorwatch.com
```

What is wrong in this settings?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have just added `:tls: true` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ports with `:enable_starttls_auto: true` option   :

```
SMTP    25
SMTP Alternate  26
SMTP Alternate  587
SMTP - SSL  465
```